# create a thread that will write each character typed using keyboard

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keyboard, keylistener

I am trying to create a **`thread`** that will create a `text file` and will write each and every character typed on computer using key listener but i am not getting how do i append the created file with next character that user will enter.....might be i am confusing everyone but i just want to store each and every character that user will type (through keyboard)

Its like whenever i execute my application it will create an file and start writing the **`keychar`** into that file.

Comment: How are you writing the file currently?

Comment: `write each and every character typed on computer` - Java doesn't support this. You only have access to KeyEvents for the Java application that currently has focus.

Comment: Please paste the sample code that you may have. We can take a look at it and suggest solution based on it.

Comment: I dont think there is way to write to file in this way in Java. The rough soln can be, you can buffer (File- Buffered )characters from keyboard and flush it after some interval to file

Comment: @ajduke Of course files can be appended, you just need to open them correctly

Comment: might be my explanation is bit confusing in other word i can say that i am trying to implement a keylogger which will run in background or can be run on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. Firstly if you want to to store each and every character typed on system, then is a tough task (explained later). If at all the you want to register the key-strokes with your Java window on top, then you can achieve that, by not closing the file and appending to the same `writer`.

Hence it will keep appending to it. But make sure, all the key handling occurs inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Now if at all the task, it for any window. Then it is tedious, firstly because you need the OS support for it. You will have to use `JNI` or preferably `JNA`. For windows, [this](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/package-summary.html) will help. I am unclear of which appropriate function to use, but you will find all the desired here (Though you will need to look at win32 api first)

```
private final User32 lib = = User32.INSTANCE;
//lib.appropriateMethod
```

Similarly for Mac, using [Carbon](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref.pdf) Framework (deprecated) or `Cocoa`.

This is the pain, if you do it in Java

Comment: Jatin as u stated i have to create an instance of User32 but i think it will provide each and every steps like copying one file or executing some operation

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get your statement. Can you pl elaborate

Comment: I am saying that does user32 reflects all the operations performed by user or it just represent the keyboard instance

Comment: It has the necessary functions, using which you can get key strokes. But rather I would suggest, that you try doing it in Visual ++ or C#. It will get over in quarter of a time with lesser effort. JNA is a big pain. A single bit here to there will just crash your JVM right there. Of you are doing it on JVM, I suggest go through the documentation of JNA and platform thoroughly. PS: I jsut wasted a month working on it, hence the experience :)

Comment: thanx jatin i have done this thing in vb but i want to make that application run till user shut down the os

Comment: till that time i have used timer to close that app but pls if any one know how to close an vb app when user chooses shut down